Autofill After Filling A Column
To give some background on what I am trying to achieve we use serial numbers that have two characters followed by four digits an example being UX8555. The issue I am running into is that when we export from a tool we get the said serial UX8555 with a quantity of X in this case "3". I am very novice on macros and have only edited a handful so I don't understand it in its entirety.
So far, other than autofilling once the macro is complete I can not get the Serial to increment by 1. If there was a way that instead of duplicating the serial and it could just be incremented by the quantity followed by it UX8555 with a quantity of 3 would bring us to UX8555, UX8556, and UX8557. But the current macro completes it as UX8555, UX8555, UX8555.
The following code is what I have:
Option Explicit

    Sub companyemployees()
    
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim z As Integer
    Dim w As Integer
    
    
    For i = 2 To 1000
    
    j = Cells(i, 2).Value
    
    For z = 2 To j + 1
    
    Cells(z + w, 4).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
    Cells(z + w, 5).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value

Next
w = w + z - 1
'the above line used to be w = w + z - 2 changing it to a 1 inserts a space between each fleet'

Next i

End Sub

